# Binding element 'users' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

Trying to fetch data using api in react and typescript though it's giving me an error.i want to display the data from the json api.i am new to react and typescript.
i am using useEffect function to call the api.the below code is in src/components/Home.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
//import  styledComponents from "styled-components";

// Could not find a declaration file for module 'styled-components'. '/var/www/html/public_html/react_js/myapp_task/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
//   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/styled-components` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'styled-components';`

import backgroundImage from "./background.png";

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json.slip.users);
        setUsers(json.slip.users);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  //return (
      const Table = ({ users }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Region</th>
          <th>Memory</th>
          <th>CPUs</th>
          <th>Disk Size</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        { (users.length > 0) ? users.map( (users, index) => {
           return (
            <tr key={ index }>
              <td>{ users.id }</td>
              <td>{ users.name }</td>
              <td>{ users.username.slug}</td>
              <td>{ users.email}</td>
              <td>{ users.address}</td>
              <td>{ users.street}</td>
              <td>{ users.suite}</td>
            </tr>
          )
         }) : <tr><td colSpan="5">Loading...</td></tr> }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify type of props

```
type YourUserType = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    username: {
        slug: string
    },
    email: string,
    address: string,
}

const Table = ({ users }: { users: YourUserType[] }) => {
```

If You are starting best place to learn about typescript+react is to use https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react

Comment: where exactly `const Table = ({ users }) => {`

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: `TS1005: '}' expected.` after updating i getting this error

Comment: `type YourUserType = {` what do you mean by `YourUserType`

Comment: Please consider https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react

Comment: `'Home' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element. in typescript`  this the error i am getting